# R shiny: run code if req not satisfied (equivalent to "req else"?)

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny app, I check the validity of an input with `req` and update an output if the requirement on the input is TRUE (i.e. not empty, not FALSE, etc.).

**I would like to run some code if the `req` is FALSE, i.e. use a `req() else {}`-like structure.**

I could use an `if() {} else {}` conditional structure, but the `req` tests many things that I would prefer to avoid implementing myself.

**Here is a MWE:**

- If the input `text_in` is valid, a reactive value `local$text` is updated.
- The content of the reactive value is then printed to the output `text_out`.
- When the input `text_in` is not valid, I would like to execute some code, e.g. `local$text <- "no text"`

**Note:** I could run `local$text <- "no text"` before using the `req` but the app I am developing (not this example) uses multiple `req` and I cannot define a "default" value before calling these `req`.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("text_in", label = "write", value = "default"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text_out", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    local <- reactiveValues(text = NULL)
    
    observe({
        req(input$text_in)
        local$text <- input$text_in
        # else {
        #     local$text <- "no text"
        # }
        
    })
    
    output$text_out <- renderText({
        local$text
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**Solution** proposed by @[mr-putter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14348996/mr-putter) using `shiny::isTruthy`:

```r
observe({
    if(isTruthy(input$text_in)) {
        local$text <- input$text_in
    } else {
        local$text <- "no text"
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you use `shiny::isTruthy` in an `if` statement?

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! You could write an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Someone proposed an answer according to your suggestion, I mention your name in the original post as the one who find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req` returns "the first value that was passed in". So, you should be able to do something like this:

```
observe({
    if(isTruthy(input$text_in))
       local$text <- input$text_in
    else {
        local$text <- "no text"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is not working as expected, the whole `if() {} else {}` is still skipped. Finally, using `shiny::isTruthy` in the if condition will do the trick.

Comment: Changed it accordingly. Thanks.